# Nib View not showing menu or navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

In an app I'm working on I have a profile tab where the user can see all the information associated to their account, one of the fields is the university they attend and next to the field is a button where they can select from a table view of values the university they go to. Here is a screenshot of the profile view:

[image]

When I tap the select button, it takes me to another view that has the table with the list of universities, once I select one, it takes me back to the profile view, except when i get back to the profile view the navigation bar and the buttom menu are missing:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to go between view controllers:

```
ProfileView * vc = [[ProfileView alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: You should present a view controller but not a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `ProfileView` a subclass of `UIView` or `UIViewController`? In the latter case it should be renamed to `ProfileViewController` as the current name suggests that its a custom view. Otherwise, as comments suggest, you need to create a UIViewController for that view, if you going to use the following methods:

**Presenting the detail view controller:**

You're using `[self presentViewController]` which will simply present a view controller by sliding it from the bottom of the screen. On completion it can be dismissed with `[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion]`. If you want a navigation bar to be included you can either:

- Add a UINavigationBar to the presented view controller's view.
- Put the presented view controller inside a navigation controller.

For the latter case:

```
[self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] 
    initWithRootViewController:vc]];
```

Alternatively, you can push the next view controller onto the current navigation controller's stack using:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

. . . and this would slide the view controller across from the right.

Finally, for some alternative approaches, if you wished you could present the ViewController and/or view using:

- `[UIView transitionWithView . . . ]`
- CAKeyFrameAnimation

. . however these should not be needed according to the requirements you describe in your question.

Comment: It was a UIViewController, i ended up using dismissViewControllerAnimated, thanks for you help!